# How to keep Bazel from downloading failing test logs

Tags: bazel

I'm running a bazel build against a Remote Build Execution endpoint; on the machine with the bazel client, there's very little local storage, so I want to avoid downloading anything.

`--remote_download_outputs=minimal` avoids downloading build artifacts, but I see that failing tests still have their log downloaded (and possibly the associated `test.xml` + undeclared outputs zip files as well). Even trying to tell bazel not to print test failure info (via `--test_summary=none`) didn't stop these downloads. The files should still be discoverable via the Build Event Stream, and AFAIK there's no need to download them to get the details necessary to announce them in the stream.

Unfortunately, in certain cases these test outputs can still be very large. How can I avoid downloading any files to the client machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, there is no way currently; file a feature request.

The long story: `--remote_download_minimal` will suppress the download of most test outputs like `test.xml`. The problem is that `test.log` and `test.err` are not normal file outputs. Bazel [always downloads the stdout and stderr of all actions](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/66ac39c793605cc08d6f3c0a83401f3fdbb03f1b/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/remote/RemoteExecutionService.java#L1180) regardless of how `--remote_download_outputs` is set. The output of normal build actions goes to the console, but Bazel writes test stdout and stderr to `test.log` and `test.err` files in the `bazel-testlogs` tree.